# Shapes & categories

Tags: qgis, shapefile, sqlite

I am very new to this so please only smile if a dumb question.  I have divided the oceans into 31 regions.  Each region has various sub regions, example I have region 08; of which it is further broken down to region 0801; region 0802....

Also, my end game is having all of this data in a SQLite database for use in an iOS APP.

I have already defined these regions and subregions in Google Earth.  I am exported them into kml format and know how to import them.  However, two questions:

- I am not sure if it is better to create one shape, called Region 08 and have this shape with categories equaled to the sub regions.  I am not sure if the db or app can see each category within a shape; or do I need to import each region and subregion as an individual shape.
- My database has two tables, RL_Regions and RL_Subregions.  All of the data is there (already imported from Google earth).  Is it easier to extract the data from the db and create shapes, or to create the shapes first and add to the db?

I really have tried to research this on my own, but nothing seems to match with what I need.  Unfortunately, the app is nearly completed and I do not have the luxury of flexibility with the db design.

Comment: I think how you store the data depends on how you want to analyze the data and if you will be editing it. One layer containing all the regions and subregions might be a way to go if you are going to edit it or if you want to analyze all regions together.

Comment: I don't see myself editing the data very often.  Once it is set, it will be good without changes.  Am I to believe that SQLite will be able to define a subregion if it is set as a category of a shape?

Comment: Yes if I understand the data correctly. Each subregion would have its own shape and would be categorized with a unique subregion name and non-unique region name. Then you can query that any way you want.